# Wildfly deployment scanner "jbosstoolsscanner1"

Tags: wildfly, jboss-tools

I have standalone installation of Wildfly server on path C:\Tools\wildfly-10.1.0.Final and in standalone.xml defined following deployment scanner:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
    <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
</subsystem>
```

For developing Java EE apps I use Eclipse IDE with JBoss Tools pluging for enterpirse development. Recently I started to use latest Eclipse update (Oxygen 3) with newest JBoss Tools 4.5.2 Final.

When I configure new Wildfly server and start using it it automaticali inserts fallowing scanner in standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
    <deployment-scanner name="jbosstoolsscanner1" path="C:\Tools\wildfly-10.1.0.Final\standalone" deployment-timeout="5000"/>
</subsystem>
```

This scanner starts to deploy bunch of files to Wildfly including standalone.xml, then Wildfly goes nuts.

How to disable this automatic scanner or at least how to change folder which this scanner scans (to change path attribute to proper deployments folder of Wildfly)?

Comment: Just don't use the `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone` directory and that shouldn't happen.

Comment: I have the same question.

Answer (score 7):

To disable the Deployment Scanner, stop your Wildfly. In Eclipse open the Servers-View and double-click on your server. In 'Deployment Scanners' uncheck the following options:

- Add missing deployment scanners after server startup
- Remove added deployment scanners before shutdown

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. I manually modified standalone-full.xml to remove deployment-scanner for *jbosstoolsscanner1*. That has fixed it for me. I am not very sure though if this has any side-effects.